# Cloning my old Crucial SSD to my new computer BUT don't want to clone the operatring system?

Tags: ssd, clone

My new computer has a up to date windows operating system that I wish to retain.
But I want to clone my old (Crucial SSD) without the old operating system.
How would I do this?

Comment: Please bring additional details: are the drives (old and new) removable? Do you plan using an intermediate (external) drive, or cloning/copying directly the old to the new one? Anyway you may just manually copy/paste the files you want to keep, or read this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-easy-transfer-is-not-available-in-windows-10-ff30fba8-9b3e-58f8-5cf2-dfabae35fa01#:~:text=However%2C%20Microsoft%20has%20partnered%20with,your%20new%20Windows%2010%20PC.

Comment: Programs have to be reinstalled, no way around this. Other data can simply be copied.

Comment: Hi, the old ssd is removable. I don't want to open up my new computer as I would lose my warranty. So I'll be cloning the old ssd drive onto a new computer.

Comment: OK is this the way to proceed. Clone the old ssd onto the new computer. Then re-install the new computer operating system. Is that correct?

Comment: P.S. as per MOAb suggestion

Comment: I suppose if all elsew fails I can always do a factory reset. lol

Comment: @LlewTudor No: what Moab was saying is: 1) Install the programs you need on the new computer; 2) Copy the data onto the new computer. You might need to find licence numbers for the programs, and you might need to uninstall some of them from the old computer before you can install them on the new computer.

Comment: @LlewTudor If (according to your initial question) you don't want to replace the OS the new PC by the OS of the old PC, then you should NOT clone the disk. And in my opinion this is reasonnable to NOT replace the whole OS.

Comment: @LlewTudor If you clone the old disk into the new computer, you will lose the ability to do a factory reset because the data needed will have been written over.